# Vim command behaving differently at end of line

Tags: vim

I have defined several maps that encaspulate a selected piece of text, e.g. to convert "text" to "\texttt{text}". This is one example for such a map:

```
vmap <buffer> ,t xi\texttt{<Esc>pa}<Esc>
```

However, this map does not work as expected when the selected text is at the end of the line.
Take for example this line:

```
word1 word2 word3
```

when I execute the normal command `viw,t` for every word in the line, this is the result that I get:

```
\texttt{word1} \texttt{word2}\texttt{word3}
```

with a trailing space, i.e. the insert of the last `texttt{` happened at the wrong place.

How can I change my map to work regardless of where it is executed?

Comment: The problem is the cursor position after the x, which is different at the EOL, because there's no trailing char to put the cursor to. Using s as suggested might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `s` instead of `xi`. That deletes the selection and goes straight into insert mode avoiding the uncertain cursor position after deleting with `x`.

`vmap <buffer> ,t s\texttt{<Esc>pa}<Esc>`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
:nnoremap <buffer> ,t ciw\texttt{<C-R>"}<Esc>
```

You don't need to select the word first, just make sure that the cursor is on it somewhere.
See `:help text-objects` and `:help i_CTRL-R`. Also :nmap would work as well as `:nnoremap` in this case, but `:nnoremap` is good practice since it prevents the RHS of the mapping triggering any nested or recursive mappings.

Comment: I usually select more text than just a single word. But it's a nice addition to my existing vmap!

Comment: Then use `:vnoremap <buffer> ,t s\texttt{<C-R>"}<Esc>`. The other answer won't work if your selection spans more than one line.

Comment: With selections spanning more than one line, the space just after my selection gets eaten with this map.

Comment: So it does. That looks like a bug. This should work though: `:vnoremap <buffer> ,t s\texttt{<Esc>p\`]a}<Esc>`.